# prohibitive keymapping with putty, gnu screen and vim

Tags: linux, ssh, vim, putty, gnu-screen

I'm logged in to my Debian machine using putty. I have a GNU screen session open and I am running vim in it. the problem I have is that when I go to save the file using `:w<enter>` this appears to translate to `M<newline>` in vim! The combination of these programs is doing it - if I just use vim without gnu screen then the problem goes away.

How can I prevent putty-gnuscreen-vim from translating the `:w<enter>` character sequence?

I looked at the putty settings and the only one that looks relevant is:

`terminal > keyboard > the function keys > ESC[n~`

I have tried changing this to `linux` and `vt100+` but it has no effect on the problem.

also

```
$ echo $TERM
screen
```

Comment: The first thing I ask people to check in this kind of situation is to make sure that their `TERM` environmental variable is set to "`screen`" within screen. If not, that's a problem and must be fixed.

Comment: i just checked. it is unfortunately.